# dynamic struct array resizing when passed by reference

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamically-generated

i don't get what's causing a segfault **after** the first round of the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct query_param {
  char *key;
  char *val;
};

void extract_params(struct query_param **query_params, char *query_string,
                    size_t *query_params_len) {
  char *token, *key;

  while (query_string != NULL) {
    token = strsep(&query_string, "&");
    key = strsep(&token, "=");

    *query_params = realloc(*query_params, (*query_params_len + 1) *
                                               sizeof(struct query_param));


    query_params[*query_params_len]->key = malloc(strlen(key));
    query_params[*query_params_len]->val = malloc(strlen(token));

    memcpy(query_params[*query_params_len]->key, key, strlen(key));
    memcpy(query_params[*query_params_len]->val, token, strlen(token));

    (*query_params_len)++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *query_string = "foo=bar&baz=boo&zip=zap";
  size_t query_params_len = 0;
  struct query_param *query_params = NULL;
  extract_params(&query_params, query_string, &query_params_len);
  return 0;
}
```

adding the first key value pair to the struct works fine but the **second malloc** is causing **trouble**.

valgrind info:

```
==15319== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15319== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15319== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15319== Command: ./a.out
==15319== 
==15319== 
==15319== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15319==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4008DF
==15319==    at 0x4EC1A0B: strsep (in /lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==15319==    by 0x4006C0: extract_params (foo.c:15)
==15319==    by 0x400848: main (foo.c:36)
==15319== 
==15319== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15319==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15319==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==15319== 
==15319== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15319== 
==15319== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15319== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

after running valgrind, is still don't get a grip on that issue. especially the heap summary does not make any sense to me. how can there be 0 bytes allocated after running malloc 3 times?

cheers!

Comment: No error-checking, no [mcve], no details. See [ask]!

Comment: You can debug it for yourself by compiling it with `gcc -g` (and no `-O...` flag), and running it trough `valgrind`. If you don't understand the output of `valgrind`, then copy-paste it to the question.

Comment: thanks for the input so far. after running valgrind i'm more confused than before though :D

Comment: C does not have pass-by-reference.  It supports passing pointers by value, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Consider using `strdup()` in place of `strlen()` + `malloc()` + `memcpy()`.  The former is shorter, clearer, and equivalent.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you strip of the zero-termination? Or should `strlen(blah)` really be `strlen(blah) + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 query_params[*query_params_len]->blah
```

`query_params` is not an *array of pointers*,  nor it's a pointer to the first element of an *array of pointers*. It's a pointer to a pointer to the first element of an **array of structures**. You want this

```
 (*query_params)[*query_params_len].blah
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues other then the one pointed out in @n.m. answer (`query_params` is *"a pointer to a pointer to the first element of an **array of structures**."*).

The line

```
char *query_string = "foo=bar&baz=boo&zip=zap";
```

Declares `query_string` as a pointer to a const string literal, but later the program have to modify the memory pointed due to the use of `strsep()`. You should declare an array as a copy of the const string:

```
char query_string[] = "foo=bar&baz=boo&zip=zap";
```

Also, when you try to copy the tokens, you should follow @John Bollinger suggestion and use `strdup()` or at least take the `'\0'` terminator into account.

Besides, you should check the return values of all the library function used and at the end free the allocated memory.

Comment: all of your suggestions are much appreciated and i'll take them into account gladly but @n.m. still answered what i was asking in the first place.  many thanks again though!